# Find id that are not part of a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product table with approximately 60k products. I have a list of approximately 2k ID in string format. I want to be able to select the ID of the list that does not exist in my product table.

I could create a temporary table, add all the ID to it and left join it on the product table to find out which ID does not exist but I am sure there is an easier way with just a query.

Here's a simplified version of the problem :

```
| Products |
|----------|
|id | ...  |
|1  |      |
|2  |      |
|3  |      |
|5  |      |
------------    

List of ID : 2,3,4
```

I want to have the result `4`

Ideally, I would like to do a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (2,3,4) ids
LEFT OUTER JOIN products 
ON ids.id = products.id 
HAVING products.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use that type solution, I would rewrite it as:

```
SELECT ids.id 
FROM (SELECT 2 AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 3
      UNION
      SELECT 4) AS ids
LEFT OUTER JOIN products 
 ON ids.id = products.id 
WHERE products.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is converting your delimitted list of values (on one row) into multiple rows. For that I believe you should use a custom function. Here is one you can use:

**Step 1: Custom Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION strsplit(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), pos int) returns varchar(255)
return replace(substring(substring_index(x, delim, pos), length(substring_index(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

Taken from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

**Step 2: Create a "numbers" table**

You said you have 2,000 something records on the delimitted list you're using for the search. Take the exact number, and create a "numbers" table with however rows going from 1, 2, 3, etc. up through however many IDs you're going to search on. So if you're searching on 2,335 IDs, open up excel, create a list going from 1 to 2,335, and import it as a one column table. Note: This table just has to have an ascending list of numbers, it in no way relates to the IDs you'll be searching on, it just needs to have one row for each ID you'll be searching on, with an ascending count. (refer to sql fiddle example). Because it's not your search list and is just a continuous series of #s, you should be able to do this painlessly in Excel and then import via phpmyadmin.

**Step 3: Run your query, using the custom function, and "numbers" table**

```
select strsplit(ids.id, ',', numbers.numbers) as missing
  from ids, numbers
 where ids.id not in (select id from products)
```

**SQL Fiddle here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8282/3/0

Comment: On a side note, if you'll be doing this often and you don't always want to know how many IDs are within the delimitted list, create a numbers table that has a very large range (like 1 to 99,999) and count the ocurrences of ',' within your string (using LENGTH(REPLACE())) and add a line of criteria that limits numbers.numbers to be <= to that count. That should allow you to do this on an ongoing basis without worrying about the exact # of IDs are in your search list.

Comment: This will work but in my question, I said I do not want to create a temporary table.

Comment: The temporary table does not need to contain the IDs, which is what you said you wanted to avoid, "I could create a temporary table, add all the ID to it". This is just a consecutive string of numbers. In Oracle you could just use the connect by clause to do this but with mysql your options are limited.